# Scheduling not calculating properly

Tags: ms-project

In Office version 2007, I have some tasks that are all fixed duration.  I'm a prime contractor with subcontractors and I'm trying to schedule out events.  I have add the duration and assigned the resources, however on some of them I count up the days and they don't add up correctly or one does not start until another ends.  Here is an example:

Task ID 4 - Design Approval Start Fri 8/29/29/2014 Finish 9/5/2014
Then I have order equipment with each manufacture having a different lead time for delivery and all the predecessors are on task ID 4.
Task 6 Vendor 1 Duration 2 wks Tue 9/9/2014 Finish 9/23/2014 Resource Company A
Task 7 Vendor 2 Duration 3 wks Fri 11/14/2012 Finish Wed 12/10/2014 Resource A

See the problem task 7 should start on the same day as Task 6 because the predecessor is the same task ID 4.

All constraints are as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Chris, to be specific, can you clarify what your exact question is? Also, I think JulieS had some questions in the answer that you might be able to address with an [edit] to your post.  Just so you know, any edits will bump this back to the top for our [community to re-evaluate and possibly reopen for more answers](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are having this problem because you assign the same resource to all the tasks.

If your tasks are in auto-schedule mode then msproject will auto level your resources based on the availability. You can raise the resource availability set to %200 (or more depending on the concurent tasks) from resource sheet or assign another resource to the task to make them not have a FS relationship or make the tasks manually-scheduled. In the last case you will get warnings about over-allocation of the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have different resources assigned to Task 7, resource leveling would not be an issue.

However, there are a couple of questions.  If Task 6 is linked to task 4 in a F to S relationship without any lag, the task should start on Sept 8, Monday.

Have you modified the project calendar in any way?
Have you modified the Resource A's calendar in any way?

Comment: Hey Julie, thanks for your contributions to PMSE. If a question isn't clear, we try to use the comments under the question to seek clarification. That way, answers are reserved for 100% solid answers to the question. I put the post on hold for now. If you want more details from the asker, please feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  As I'm sure you have experienced, OP often don't come back for either clarification or to say whether the question has been resolved or not :-)

Comment: In that case, if they don't come back, the question eventually gets auto deleted, assuming all questions and answers are negatively or zero-scored. Our end-goal is to help not just the asker, but most importantly, to help all of the future visitors who would have the same problem. Comments on unclear questions help lead us to that goal. Hope this helps clarify.